# Where in Sweden can I celebrate midsommar with the locals?

Tags: public-transport, local-customs, sweden

I live in Copenhagen and I would like to attend a *midsommar* celebration in Sweden on the 24th. Do you have any suggestion on where to go? Ideally, it should be in a small place, reachable using public transport.

Comment: Sankthans is a Danish thing, it's *midsommar* in Sweden.  Which one are you looking for?

Comment: midsommar! I just edited the question

Comment: Probably just take an Öresundståg into Sweden and get off at the first not-so-large place behind Lund ;)

Comment: More about traditional swedish midsummer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48036/are-there-public-midsummers-eve-events-near-stockholm-i-could-attend/48046).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too late, but for future reference and other people who are wondering:

I celebrated near Skövde. Every place we visited or passed on a roadtrip after midsommar had a midsommarstång, so you can go to basically any city. 
Examples near Copenhagen/Lund are Falsterbö and Vikhög.
Pick a city, and search google images for "cityname midsommar", to see where they celebrate, as it differs in every place (some use a park in the village, others a castle, some might be on a beach, ... ).
So pick a place and see if you can reach it by public transport. Or pick a place you can reach, and see if it's good for you. Since most people don't celebrate in a city, but rather in a small town, a small village doesn't mean the festivities will be small. Looking at footage from previous years should give a good impression about how and where it's celebrated in a given town.

Comment: This is really useful. I plan to visit Sweden next June and I want to party like a Swede!